# How to determine which car/truck will pull given their acceleration, top speed etc?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

So let's say if two cars were having a tug of war, pulling each other. and we know all about the cars their top speed, acceleration, towing capacity and all. how can we determine which car will pull which, and at what speed? i hope this is the right forum to ask this question. I'm looking for an equation.

Comment: Are both vehicles gas? For same horsepower l  believe a pure electric will have more torque

Comment: So what I want is that I pick any two cars and can determine which will pull which. Like the Tesla cibertruck vs. F150 or Toyota Camry vs Honda Accord.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your additional information. It doesn't solve your problem, but perhaps it can help you to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are an awful lot of variables here. There’s the maximum torque that can be generated at the drive wheel(s).  There’s the traction rating of the tires. There’s the weight of the vehicle, the greater the weight force the greater maximum static friction force between the tires and the road surface (maximum force without slipping), all other things being equal.

Overall, given the above and maybe additional variables, I think the vehicle that can develop the most torque at the drive wheel(s) without slipping will be the winner.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cars are not the same masses but friction is the same. And I guess we can get the max torque by cars horse power